# Find a strange expression that divides zero will not report an error in C language

Tags: c, gcc

I found that dividing an expression by 0 does not report an error. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me why.
here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
int main() { 
  int result = 3/10*(7/0);
  printf("%d\n", result);
  //printf("%" PRIu64, result); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04
- gcc 11.3.0

Compile result:
[image]

Run result:
[image]

I have used gdb to debug the program and i found the expression will be optimized by the compiler (my guess). so i suspect that it's a bug in gcc.
[image]

Comment: That's to be expected. Integer division by zero causes _undefined behavior_ in C.

Comment: Since division by zero is UB, isn't the compiler allowed to do anything it wants -- including "optimizing out" the division?

Comment: Also -- if you compile and run your code with `-fsanitize=undefined`, you will get an error :)

Comment: The compiler gives you a warning about it even when not asking for warnings to be turned on...

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) "Most forms of undefined behavior are run-time bugs and it is generally not the compiler's job to find them. Some compilers are nice enough to point out various common forms of undefined behavior when they can be spotted at compile-time, but compilers aren't required to do so.

So mostly this burden falls upon the human C programmer, who must know what they are doing and what they shouldn't be doing. The system is not "required" to produce segmentation faults, access violations etc."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I found that dividing an expression by 0 does not report an error. I'd appreciate it if someone could tell me why.

As far as the C language specification is concerned, division by zero produces [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  There is no requirement that the situation be diagnosed, neither at compile time nor at run time, nor any requirement for any particular result.

But in fact, your compiler *does* diagnose it, by emiting a warning.  With gcc, if you want to ensure that you can't ignore that warning then enable `-Werror` to turn warnings into errors, or else enable `-Werror=div-by-zero` if you want to be more selective about that.

> I have used gdb to debug the program and i found the expression will be optimized by the compiler (my guess).

Plausible.

> so i suspect that it's a bug in gcc.

Nope.  The division by zero is a bug in the program.  What gcc does with that may not be what you expected, but that doesn't make gcc buggy.